# 2nd order ODE most general solution and Taylor's theorem

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

**Context**:

The 2nd order ODE of the form

$$ \frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+p\frac{dy}{dx}+qy=0, $$

which has general solution of the form (assuming distinct $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$):

$$ y= A_{1}e^{\gamma_{1}x}+A_{2}e^{\gamma_{2}x}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

where $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are two arbitrary constants.

In the book "Applied Mathematics" by Schelkunoff, p.194, the author also gives the following exposition (note that primed symbols denote derivative with $x$):

*"The equation gives merely a relationship between the function and its first two derivatives... Since the coefficient of the second-order derivative is different from zero, $y$ and $y'$ may be assigned arbitrarily at the point in question without any exceptions; $y''$ is then determined uniquely. By successive differentiation of the ODE we may express all higher derivatives in terms of $y$ and $y'$ at a given point. Applying Taylor's theorem we shall get the most general **analytic** solution of the ODE.*

*"We shall be able to **claim** that the solution in (1) is the most general analytic solution if we can show that at some point, $x=0$ for instance, we can express $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ in terms of arbitrarily assigned values of $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$. We leave the proof to the reader."*

**Question:**

I don't have a problem in proving that $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are expressible in terms of $y(x_{0})$ and $y'(x_{0})$ at some point $x_{0}$, but I am not sure why we can make such general **claim** (in the second quoted paragraph) if we simply proved such connection? Why would that mean that the two solution types ($y$ given in (1) above and Taylor's expansion) be equivalent at all other points, as to make $y$ in (1) the most general solution?

When I tried to expand for Taylor's solution in terms of $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$, I got:

$$ y(x)=y(0)\left[ 1-\frac{x^{2}}{2}q +\frac{x^{3}}{3}pq+\cdots\right]+y'(0)\left[ x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}p +\frac{x^{3}}{3}(p^{2}-q)+\cdots\right],\ \ \ \ (2)$$

which can be clearly used to give $A_{1},A_{2}$ at $x=0$ in terms of $y(0),y'(0)$, without problem. But what is not clear is that proving such connection at a point basis (such as $x=0$ here) would be enough to conclude that the two solutions are equivalent in gerenal, and therefore for the form $y$ in (1) to become the most general solution according to the author's argument.

[Incidentally, if I expand the exponents in (1) as series, it is not straightforward how they can be grouped together to exactly map to those is (2).]

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you know, but this is a very simple equation for which one can avoid heavier results. In particular,one can show that there are unique solutions, which are global, given the data $y(x_0)$ and $y'(x_0)$ for a same time $x_0$. This leads to the conclusion (in view of uniqueness) that any method gives the same solution.

Comment: Are you saying that the two solutions are equivalent because of the uniqueness of the solution to this type of equation? So that the pair $(A_{1},A_{2})$ corresponding to a given pair $(y(x_{0}),y'(x_{0}))$ will give a unique solution in terms of $A_{i}$ that must be effectively equivalent to that unique solution in terms of $y, y'$? And is it easy to prove uniqueness of solution in both cases/methods?

Comment: The is no notion of "equivalent solutions". What do you mean by equivalent? Equal?

Comment: Yes, equal in value at all points, but have different form.

Comment: I don't understand, if they are equal, they are equal, they cannot have different "forms". What are forms? Sure, functions can be expressed in different ways, they can for example perhaps be expressed by a power series, but equal really means equal, there is no way around it.

Comment: As for your question on how to prove it, that's what I meant by "It really depends on what you know". The statement is proved in any good initial course in differential equations, so you can grab your favorite book (with proofs) and look it there (avoid very bad books such as Braun, and very good books such as Arnold).

Comment: Of course different forms (or "ways" as you call them) exist in mathematics. Plenty of "forms" are talked about in classic text by Morse & Feshback, for example. Anyway, thanks for your answer. I think I got what you meant.

Comment: Never heard of "Morse & Feshback", sorry, but I guess that you have a reply now, from a mathematician... :)

Comment: Sure ;)  People from different backgrounds naturally may express things in slightly different languages sometimes. Many thanks. (by the way, Morse & Feshback's book, though in theoretical physics and applied maths, might be of interest, even to a mathematician, if working on applied techniques).